# Form.io: Recommended way to have repeating complex objects on a form

Tags: angularjs, formio

I'm trying to get to grips with [form.io](https://form.io/#/)

I've got two objects: Qualification and Examination. A Qualification can contain multiple Examinations. Both objects also have several standard text fields.

Could someone tell me the recommended way to build a form that allows the user to enter multiple Qualifications (and their Examinations)? Like this:

[image]

Is this possible with form.io? I thought it would be by defining resources (e.g. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrLGT2N_ayk&list=PLL9kNSjqyfJ7F0F_guO5q_fSXkPTaz_Pl&index=3) tutorial talks about nesting them), but don't think really achieves what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done by using the Datagrid component. This allows grouping multiple fields together in an object. You can then add another datagrid within the datagrid to create the examinations inside a qualification. Datagrid is under Special components.

Comment: Thanks Randall, I did wonder if Datagrid might be the answer. Couldn't find much documentation about it but if that's the recommended approach I'll put a bit more effort in that direction.

Comment: I can see how this would work now (just had a bit of a play), thanks for the tip

Comment: Just for anyone else reading this, I've created an outer DataGrid and the first thing in that is a Panel so I can lay out the first few text fields vertically, then another DataGrid to hold the repeating Examination fields. I've not bothered with a panel inside that one because I'm happy with the Examination fields being laid out side by side in a table.

Comment: Just an FYI Randall, the fields in the 2nd level objects (Examinations in my case) export to Json fine, but don't seem to work with the CSV export. Json is probably fine for us but I thought I'd mention it in case it's a genuine bug and you weren't already aware of it.

Comment: can you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650006/how-to-give-dummy-values-to-formio-form