# how to give dummy values to formio form

Tags: angular, formio

I have created a username and password with submit button page using `formio`

and I have shown in the page by taking that script from the database.
the page is visible now. But I want to show a dummy username and password when I click on a button.

But I have achieved like whenever the page loads the data will fill by adding below.

```html
    <formio [form]="obj"[submission]='{
        "data": {
          "userName": "Joe",
          "password": "Smith"
        }
      }'>
```

But I want to fill the data when I have clicked on a button.
Actually my intention is that I want to access that username in my component. How can I access that username

Ex:-
In angularJS, we can access that with `ng-model` like `$scope.ngModel`
in formio how can we access that in a component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can achieve this in component level even.

change your html as below

```
<formio [form]="obj" [submission]="submission"/>
```

add the following in your component

```
submission: any;

    showData () {
        this.submission = {
          data: {
              userName: 'Joe',
              password: 'Smith'
          }
        };
      }
```

it should display the data in page.

Happy coding :)